# Fitting model gives NULL

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, random-forest

I want to train the models using different algorithms. For instance, this work:

```
dd=read.arff("china.arff")
model=lm(Effort~ ., data=dd)
fitted(model)
```

But the following code gives NULL for the same dataset

```
install.packages("neuralnet")
library(neuralnet)
model=neuralnet(Effort~N_effort+Duration, data=dd, 
                   hidden=1,err.fct="ce", linear.output=FALSE)
fitted(model)
```

//Gives NULL

Similar result is shown with randomForest model

It is not possible that these models have no errors, so what should be the problem?

```
structure(list(Output = c(150, 98, 27, 60, 69, 19, 14, 17, 64, 
60, 27, 17, 41, 40, 12, 38, 57, 20, 66, 112, 28, 68, 15, 15), 
    Inquiry = c(75, 70, 0, 20, 1, 0, 0, 15, 14, 20, 29, 8, 16, 
    20, 13, 24, 12, 24, 13, 21, 4, 0, 6, 0), RawFPcounts = c(1750, 
    1902, 535, 660, 478.89, 377.33, 256.25, 262.73, 715.79, 690.43, 
    465.45, 298.67, 490.59, 802.35, 220, 487.62, 550.91, 363.64, 
    1073.91, 1310, 476.19, 694, 189.52, 273.68), AdjFP = c(1750, 
    1902, 428, 759, 431, 283, 205, 289, 680, 794, 512, 224, 417, 
    682, 209, 512, 606, 400, 1235, 1572, 500, 694, 199, 260), 
    Effort = c(102.4, 105.2, 11.1, 21.1, 28.8, 10, 8, 4.9, 12.9, 
    19, 10.8, 2.9, 7.5, 12, 4.1, 15.8, 18.3, 8.9, 38.1, 61.2, 
    3.6, 11.8, 0.5, 6.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

Comment: can you please provide your data using dput().

Comment: @Hunaidkhan, Im sorry I dont know about dput.. My dataset is about software effort estimation, which have several input features and "Effort" as output. It has 499 instances

Comment: @Hunaidkhan, I got the data using dput() and it is a long list but it has 0 values.. So is the problem due to 0 values??

Comment: What do you mean you don't know about dput? Just type `?dput` in the console and start reading. In addition, there's a [whole set of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that will help you to convey enough information for us to at least make an educated guess.

Comment: I edited the question and included the details of dput()

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, `fitted` is not widely used in R (except perhaps in the context of GLM models); to be honest, I had never heard of the function before (and I have been programming in R for ~ 7 years now).

So, it should not come as a surprise that, outside the context of (generalized) linear models, i.e. in models like neural networks or random forests, the method is actually not implemented, and it simply returns NULL.

The good news may come from asking yourself *why exactly you would like to use* `fitted`? Because, in practice and broadly speaking, `fitted` is roughly equivalent to `predict`, at least for simple linear models:

```
df <- data.frame(income=c(5,3,47,8,6,5),
               won=c(0,0,1,1,1,0),
               age=c(18,18,23,50,19,39),
               home=c(0,0,1,0,0,1))

md1 <- lm(income ~ age + home, data=df) # linear model



fitted(md1)
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
 7.893273  7.893273 28.320749 -1.389725  7.603179 23.679251 

predict(md1)
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
 7.893273  7.893273 28.320749 -1.389725  7.603179 23.679251
```

while in the case of GLMs you just need to specify `type='response'` when predicting, in order for the two functions to again return practically identical results:

```
md2 <- glm(factor(won) ~ age + home, data=df, family=binomial(link="logit")) #glm

fitted(md2)
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
0.4208590 0.4208590 0.4193888 0.7274819 0.4308001 0.5806112 

predict(md2)
         1          2          3          4          5          6 
-0.3192480 -0.3192480 -0.3252830  0.9818840 -0.2785876  0.3252830 

predict(md2, type='response')
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
0.4208590 0.4208590 0.4193888 0.7274819 0.4308001 0.5806112
```

So, while `fitted` for a random forest model gives indeed NULL:

```
library(randomForest)
rf <- randomForest(income ~ age + home, data=df)
fitted(rf)
NULL
```

you can arguably get your required results simply with `predict`:

```
predict(rf)
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
 9.748170 11.463800  5.186755 13.905696  8.791710 29.000931
```

The following threads might also be useful:

[Is there a difference between the R functions fitted() and predict()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201439/is-there-a-difference-between-the-r-functions-fitted-and-predict)

[Finding the fitted and predicted values for a statistical model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34076/finding-the-fitted-and-predicted-values-for-a-statistical-model)