# Need for print() function in R

Tags: r, printing

Sometimes I read posts where people use the `print()` function and I don't understand why it is used. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201439/is-there-a-difference-between-the-r-functions-fitted-and-predict) for example in one answer the code is

```
print(fitted(m))
#         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
# 0.3668989 0.6083009 0.4677463 0.8685777 0.8047078 0.6116263 0.5688551 0.4909217 
#         9        10 
# 0.5583372 0.6540281
```

But using fitted(m) would give the same output. I know there are situations where we need `print()`, for example if we want [create plots inside of loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678261/r-ggplot-does-not-work-if-it-is-inside-a-for-loop-although-it-works-outside-of). But why is the `print()` function used in cases like the one above?

Comment: I guess for didactic reasons (to make it obvious that this code is intended to print). There used to be rare cases (hopefully fixed successfully with the current R version), where `print` and auto-printing did not print exactly the same result but the linked example probably wasn't one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing, as I rarely use `print` myself:

- using `print()` makes it obvious which lines of your code do printing and which ones do actual staff. It might make re-reading your code later easier.
- using `print()` explicitly might make it easier to later refactor your code into a function, you just need to change the `print` into a `return`
- programmers coming from a language with strict syntax might have a strong dislike towards the automatic printing feature of r

Answer (score 4):

I guess that in many cases usage of `print` is just a *bad/redundant* habit, however `print` has a couple of interesting options:

Data:

```
x <- rnorm(5)
y <- rpois(5, exp(x))
m <- glm(y ~ x, family="poisson")
m2 <- fitted(m)
#         1         2         3         4         5 
# 0.8268702 1.0523189 1.9105627 1.0776197 1.1326286
```

`digits` - shows wanted number of digits

```
print(m2, digits = 3) # same as round(m2, 3)
#     1     2     3     4     5 
# 0.827 1.052 1.911 1.078 1.133
```

`na.print` - turns `NA` values into a specified value (very similar to `zero.print` argument)

```
m2[1] <- NA
print(m2, na.print = "Failed")
#        1        2        3        4        5 
#   Failed 1.052319 1.910563 1.077620 1.132629
```

`max` - prints wanted number of values

```
print(m2, max = 2) # similar to head(m2, 2)
#        1        2 
#       NA 1.052319
```